# Is there a way to add an external transparent PNG overlay to a PDF without modifying the PDF?

Tags: pdf, music, editing, overlay

I'm trying to find an application that will let you create an overlay to a PDF but doesn't actually modify the PDF, e.g. saves a transparent `.png` that (in the program) is linked to the PDF or creates a file that you can select to add as the overlay (that is editable). That way I can share the original but have all my notes.

The purpose for this is to get music and make notes without changing the original.

I've had a look around and can't find anything that does that. Does anyone know anything that does this?

Comment: So essentially you want to take notes on a PDF but not save the notes to the file itself, correct?

Comment: Make a copy. Save notes on the copy. Share the original. The entire idea of pdf is that it is entirely self-contained - **Portable** Document Format.

Comment: *"I'm trying to find an application that will ... "* - unfortunately software recommendations are [off-topic here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) but there is http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) which allows loading a PDF and annotating it. Then you can save the annotations which will create a `ORIGINAL_FILE_NAME.pdf.xoj` file. The original PDF is not modified but there is an option to export to PDF, too.